# How to fix border pixel

Tags: border, pixel

How to fix this [1]: http://tinypic.com/r/2e337y9/9 "tooltop" everytime I use border: 1px solid black; that left and right combining their pixel resulting to 2px.

Answer (score 0):

Just add borders to one side and not both.  Otherwise they will always add up.

Comment: thought so thanks i just thought that there much simple and easy way.

Answer (score 0):

By using [border-left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-left) and [border-right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-right) you can change the values of the specific sides on your border.

The only problem would be that the changes would also be applied to the outer-left border and outer-right border. By using [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) and [:last-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child) you can select the first and last sibling within a parent element.

This results in something like:

```
element {
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-right: 0;
}

parent:last-child {
   border-right: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Comment: I see so there's really no easy way I tried doing that thought there's really a proper way to do it. thanks